# ef core 3: how to migrate Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.CSharpHelper?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.0

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.CSharpHelper` is absent in EF Core 3.

I am using it to support sql server constraints install/uninstall with the EF Core Migrations.

```
public class MyCSharpHelper : CSharpHelper
{
    public MyCSharpHelper (IRelationalTypeMappingSource relationalTypeMappingSource) : base(relationalTypeMappingSource)
    {

    }

    public override string UnknownLiteral(object value)
    {
        if (value is MyConstraint[] constraints)
        {
            return ConstraintManager.ProcessConstraintLiteral(constraints);
        }
        return base.UnknownLiteral(value);
    }
}
```

How this should look in EF Core 3 ?

Comment: AFAIK CSharpHelper is still a public class. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/v3.0.0/src/EFCore.Design/Design/Internal/CSharpHelper.cs

Comment: @KexyBiscuit but it is not included into Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design package (and there are no new Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal package) :-(   There are no  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal namespace at all in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` is now a DevelopmentDependency package meaning that it won't be deployed with your application and you can't reference it in code.

If you need custom design-time services, you have to edit the PackageReference in your project as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#microsoftentityframeworkcoredesign-is-now-a-developmentdependency-package